# How to make the Shebang be able to choose the correct Python interpreter between python3 and python3.5

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, shell, shebang

I'm developing a set of script in python3, as shebang I use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Everything goes ok, but in some virtual machines where are executed the name of interpreter is `python3.5`. I will like to be able to execute my scripts in both enviroment but I can't change the filesystem of virtual machine (so I discard solutions like make a link from python3.5 to python3 )

I look at man of `env` but I don't find any way to specify a searching pattern or something like that.

I try to set an `alias` at begining of my sessions pointing to right python interpreter but env don't use it.

My unique solution is call my scripts saying which interpreter must use but is very anoying:

```
python3.5 myscript.py
```

Any idea is welcome!, thanks!

Comment: Which wretched distro only installs `python3.5` and doesn't make it a symlink to `python3` by itself?

Comment: How are you installing your scripts if you cannot store them on disk?

Comment: @tripleee good question!, I checkout from subversion in a r/w area.... It's true, I can't change installed system but I can create some intermediate script

Comment: Why don't you create a 'bootstrap' script to go through your `.py` files and adjust their shebang in accordance with the current environment?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No need to bring in separate shell and python scripts, a single file can be both!

Replace your shebang line with this sequence:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Shell commands follow
# Next line is bilingual: it starts a comment in Python, and is a no-op in shell
""":"

# Find a suitable python interpreter (adapt for your specific needs) 
for cmd in python3.5 python3 /opt/myspecialpython/bin/python3.5.99 ; do
   command -v > /dev/null $cmd && exec $cmd $0 "$@"
done

echo "OMG Python not found, exiting!!!!!11!!eleven" >2

exit 2

":"""
# Previous line is bilingual: it ends a comment in Python, and is a no-op in shell
# Shell commands end here
# Python script follows (example commands shown)

import sys
print ("running Python!")
print (sys.argv)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!, that is exactly what I was looking for. And I must admit that it is a very ingenious way to solve it, thanks again for what I learn!

Comment: I wish i could vote that up twice. That's a really good answer and one i have been searching for a long time.

Comment: Wow, this code is pure gold. Fixed my very tricky situation where I had to run Python 3 when Python 2 was the default on the environment I didn't control. well done!

Comment: I've given this answer an upvote, and a "thanks" (some new SO feature), and I wish I could give more. This is brilliant even in 2020 for handling executable scripts that require newer versions of Python such as 3.7 or 3.8, and have to deal with the fact that older OS's will have them as `python3.7` / `python3.8` - but newer OS's might have them as just `python3`.

Answer (score 3):

If you can install scripts, you can also install a wrapper called `python3.5` which simply dispatches `python3`.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec env python3 "$@"
```

You'll obviously need to `chmod a+x` this script just like the others you install.

You'll have to add the script's directory to your `PATH` *after* the system `python3.5` directory to avoid having this go into an endless loop, and only use this script as a fallback when the system doesn't already provide `python3.5`.

As you noted, `env` doesn't know or care about your personal shell aliases or functions, and doesn't provide for any dynamic calculation of the binary to run by itself; but you have the shell at your disposal (and Python of course, once you find it!) -- it simply uses the `PATH` so if you can install your other scripts in a directory which is in your `PATH` (which must be the case for the `#!/usr/bin/env` shebang to make sense in the first place) you can store this script there, too.

As noted in comments, it's weird and user-hostile to only install `python3.5` and not at least optionally make `python3` a symlink to it, so perhaps you could eventually persuade whoever maintains the image you are installing into to provide this.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change the filesystem of virtual machine, so I can't install scripts

Comment: Wherever you are storing your Python files with the `#!/usr/bin/env python3.5` shebang, you can also store this wrapper script. There is no way you can achieve one but not the other.

Comment: As i pointed I can't change system, I only have a folder where I can write, and I checkout there my scripts

Comment: Right. So store this script too there.

Comment: Maybe actually call this `python3` and have it dispatch `python3.5` rather than the other way around.  Then you can keep `#!/usr/bin/env python3` which makes sense outside of your sicko environment, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a shell script that uses python 3.5 if it is installed, otherwise uses python 3 and executes your script with the correct version.
No need for python shebang.
In your shell script you may test if `which python3.5` returns something; if it does, then python3.5 is installed, otherwise you'd have to use `python3`

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change the filesystem of virtual machine, so I can't install scripts